# How does Network providers dialog appear in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, service-provider

When call disconnects or text message is send then
 our service provider account balance get reduce and they show a dialog box or pop-up with related text of account balance left and money detected.
So how that dialog box appears ?

Is there any default network provider app is installed in system to get those notification or Is this is any android push notification or Android system is taking care of those pop-ups or something else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the TelephonyManager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Heres an example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23440052/2272188

And also Content Observer for texts

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

Example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5808648/2272188